# Where can I find the source for type list?

Tags: python, list

Where can I find the source for Python's `list` type? I've had a quick look in [its SVN repo](http://svn.python.org/view/python/branches/release27-maint/) (2.7 branch) but it's a very scary place.

*Edit*: Since Python migrated from SVN a while back, to be more contemporary I'll link to [its HG repo](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/fb49394f75ed) (2.7 branch) as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find that code in [Objects/listobject.c](http://svn.python.org/view/python/branches/release27-maint/Objects/listobject.c?view=markup).

Beware though, it can be scarier than the repo tree :)

Answer (score 3):

Don't use the svn repository. Use the Mercurial repository, it's much easier to use. (It's also written in Python!) I've had `UnicodeDecodeError`s and such viewing the svn repo, too.

`list` is in [listobject.c](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c821e3a54930/Objects/listobject.c)

Comment: Cheers, I just updated the question to include their HG repo.